# JMeter Script Recording Issue - Proxy Working, but No Recording

Tags: jmeter

The current state of my JMeter setup and test plan is:

- JMeter 5
- Certificate Authority generated and imported into Firefox.
- Checked that the port # in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder matches that in the proxy server set up in Firefox.
- Have added a Recording Controller to my Thread Group.
- Have added Cache and Cookie Managers to my Thread Group.
- When I start the proxy server, i.e., Start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder, I can walk the example application I'm testing - including HTTPS requests. (And if the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is not started I get "The proxy server is refusing connections" message from Firefox.)
- I have ensured that the selected Target Controller in the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder is a recording controller I've added to my Thread Group.
- No Sampler/Requests are being added under the Recording Controller.

Has anyone else encountered a situation in JMeter in which the proxy server seems to be working correctly but no sampler/requests are actually being recorded? And even if this case is novel, do you have any suggestions? Thank-you in advance for your advice.

Comment: Thank-you for your excellent suggestions.  I started over with a new test plan and was able to record the script required. I was never able to debug the problem with the original script.  Just a couple of notes and the excellent suggestions:have now reset log file for debug; I did  start the new test plan from the template; my Firefox proxy and crt were generated and installed correctly. I will explore the suggested Chrome extension and Blazemeter. Thank-you all for your informative answers. ALB

Answer (score 1):

1. Take a look at [*jmeter.log* file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/hints_and_tips.html#debug_logging) - if there is an issue with your setup you should get some clues regarding what's wrong from there. It is also a good idea to add the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

   ```
   <Logger name="org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.proxy" level="debug" />
   ```

   it will increase log level verbosity for the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
2. Make sure your Firefox is configured to use the proxy **for all protocols** and there are no exclusions for `localhost`, `127.0.0.1` or your IP address/hostname

   [image]
3. Try [clearing your browsing history](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/delete-browsing-search-download-history-firefox) as it might be the case "stale" certificate is still present or something is cached.

As the last resort be aware of an alternative way of recording a JMeter test using [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium) - in this case you will not have to worry about proxies and SSL certificates.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't create your own Test Script Recorder script, simply because you can make mistakes, just use predefined JMeter's template

- Choose Menu: File -> Templates
- (Recording is selected) Click Create

Your Recording script is set

[image]

Answer (score 0):

you need to add ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA certificate in your firefox by setting
Go to tools > option > Certificate > View Certificate > import certificates.

Now restart the firefox.

Comment: Thank-you for the assistance. I don't know what I did wrong / omitted when I was stuck, but I triple checked the certificate was correctly generated, current (not expired - I resent the associated parameter in the jmeter.properties file to have the cert good for 1 year), and correctly installed in Firefox. As I mentioned in my follow-up note, I started over using the recording template and all went well. But I do want to thank everyone for their prompt and informative suggestions. Had I more patience, am sure I would have tracked down my error - but, alas, time and patience ran out.

Answer (score 0):

just a late reply but facing same issue...
Have you tried to clean the 'URL Patterns to include' in HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder ?
It did work for me and could record was the proxy was not recording.

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful.